# How to set a default file manager for qt's app?

Tags: qt, filemanager, awesome

I am running on ubuntu with awesomeWM which does not have specific file manager. When I launch vlc or any other Qt app and try to open a file from there, it does segfault after the following error message :

```
<application_name>/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found!
```

Do you know how to set a specific file manager for Qt apps and why it's expecting a kde part one ?

Basically, how does it work ? Why are only GTK's app able to open a file manager ? Is there a lib missing for Qt ? Do they both have their own default file manager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by uninstalling the following packages : kdelibs5-data kde-style-qtcurve

```
sudo apt-get remove kdelibs5-data kde-style-qtcurve
```